# How to call finish() in xml code

Tags: android, xml, preferenceactivity, preference, activity-finish

This is my code in `PreferenceFragment` `preferences.xml` that starts another activity, but what is the code that would call `finish()` so this `PrefFragment` would end?

```
<Preference
     android:key="pref_theme"
     android:title="@string/pref_theme">
     <intent android:targetPackage="com.abc.xyz"
          android:targetClass="com.abc.xyz.ThemeActivity"/>
</Preference>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not call it from the XML. You must create a class, in your case called `ThemeActivity`, and change the code there.

Comment: @Nemanja if this answer was correct, please mark it as correct so future readers know this has been solved.